# Group by title sum of data

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables like below

table1:**camp**

```
id --- user_id -- title
1 ----- 101 ----- abc
2 ----- 107 ----- xyz
3 ----- 111 ----- xmp
4 ----- 101 ----- pop
5 ----- 101 ----- xza
6 ----- 107 ----- xvc
```

table2:**exp**

```
id --- camp_id ---- view --- check --- cost
1 ------ 1 -------- 5 ------- 2 ------ 3
2 ------ 1 -------- 10 ------ 3 ------ 6
3 ------ 1 -------- 15 ------ 4 ------ 3
4 ------ 3 -------- 7 ------- 2 ------ 2
5 ------ 4 -------- 9 ------- 1 ------ 1
6 ------ 4 -------- 8 ------- 1 ------ 2
7 ------ 6 -------- 7 ------- 2 ------ 2
8 ------ 5 -------- 9 ------- 1 ------ 1
9 ------ 5 -------- 9 ------- 3 ------ 5
```

Say user_id **101** logged. I need the output for him like below. view = total of views by user_id 101 (means camp_id 1) for title abc. same way check is sum of check under each title, cost is sum of cost under each title.

```
title---view---check---cost
abc ---- 30 --- 9 ----- 12
pop ---- 17 --- 2 ----- 3
xza ---- 18 --- 4 ----- 6
```

my code :

```
SELECT c.title as t,SUM(e.view) as v,SUM(e.check) as ch,SUM(e.cost) as co 
  FROM camp c,exp e WHERE c.user_id='$log_id' AND e.camp_id=c.id 
  GROUP BY t
```

showing error. If some change then showing all title but view check cost same in every fried.

Please help

Comment: how is `camp` and `exp` related to each other?

Comment: Does mysql know that?

Comment: that is why I need a correct answer, please help

Comment: fixed that typo in an edit

Comment: That was an inappropriate edit then. That WAS the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe the below is what you are after.  You needed to JOIN the two tables together properly.  Also, you can only use an alias once in the same query.  You referenced `c` more than once.

```
SELECT c.title,
  SUM(e.view) AS viewSum,
  SUM(e.check) AS checkSum,
  SUM(e.cost) AS costSum 
FROM camp AS c 
  INNER JOIN exp AS e 
  ON c.id = e.camp_id
WHERE c.user_id = 101
GROUP BY c.title
```

Comment: Where is `user_id=101`?

Comment: **@Jungsu Heo**, better?